# Different indexes between SOLR and Lucene?

Tags: lucene, solr

I'm having issues with getting my Sitecore 8.2 sandbox to index properly. I've been using SOLR, but on a whim decided to switch over to Lucene to see if I could get the indexing to work. When I went to rebuild my indexes, I noticed about 32 different indexes, where I have only about 20 when using SOLR. I just did an upgrade from my Sitecore 8.1 environment, and I didn't see any instructions for adding new SOLR indexes to my already existing indexes. Do I need to add all of these new indexes for my SOLR indexing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your question, there are no differences in indexes between SOLR and Lucene (with the exception of the swap cores for SOLR, see Bonus Answer). What you are seeing is probably a product of too many configs activated.

Let me explain.

In Sitecore 8.2, the following indexes are active OOTB using Lucene:

- sitecore_core_index
- sitecore_master_index
- sitecore_web_index
- sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master
- sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web
- sitecore_marketing_definitions_master
- sitecore_marketing_definitions_web
- sitecore_testing_index
- sitecore_suggested_test_index
- sitecore_fxm_master
- sitecore_fxm_web
- sitecore_list_index
- social_messages_master
- social_messages_web

In a vanilla instance, the various Lucene config files for these indexes will end with `.config` indicating that they are active.  Their SOLR counterpart config would have a `.example` extension to the file.

When activating SOLR, there is a fairly onorous task of having to go through `/App_Config/Include` folder (as well as child folders) and look for Lucene files to `.disable` and **SOLR** config files to *enable* by removing the `.example` (or `.disabled` or whatever you might call it) extension.

However, not EVERY index is actually activated out of the box.

There are three files that are also left as Lucene (and SOLR) example files:
[image]

These configs, when enabled, expose a bunch more indexes:

- content_index_core
- system_index_core
- layouts_index_core
- medialibrary_index_core
- template_index_core
- content_index
- system_index
- layouts_index
- medialibrary_index
- template_index
- content_index_web
- system_index_web
- layouts_index_web
- medialibrary_index_web
- template_index_web

These indexes are not exactly required.  And when the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.<Lucene|Solr>.Indexes.Shared.<db>.config` files are enabled, they add a bunch more indexes to the indexing screen.

I believe that this is what you are seeing.

> **SUMMARY**
>
> I would venture that the three configs above are enabled. You can
>   probably safely disable them, if you don't want these extra indexes. 
>   However, yes, Sitecore is really going all in with indexing, so there
>   are a lot more indexes in Sitecore 8.2. I expect this trend to
>   continue as well.

**BONUS ANSWER**

When the SOLR Configs are enabled, and you also want to have the `SwapOnRebuild` functionality enabled, creating all of these SOLR cores can be a real chore. I've created a nice little cheat file for myself that can be used real easily with `wget` or `curl`.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_core_index&instanceDir=sitecore_core_index&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_master_index&instanceDir=sitecore_master_index&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_web_index&instanceDir=sitecore_web_index&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master&instanceDir=sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web&instanceDir=sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master&instanceDir=sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web&instanceDir=sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_testing_index&instanceDir=sitecore_testing_index&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_suggested_test_index&instanceDir=sitecore_suggested_test_index&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_fxm_master_index&instanceDir=sitecore_fxm_master_index&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_fxm_web_index&instanceDir=sitecore_fxm_web_index&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_list_index&instanceDir=sitecore_list_index&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=social_messages_master&instanceDir=social_messages_master&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=social_messages_web&instanceDir=social_messages_web&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_core_index_swap&instanceDir=sitecore_core_index_swap&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_master_index_swap&instanceDir=sitecore_master_index_swap&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_web_index_swap&instanceDir=sitecore_web_index_swap&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master_swap&instanceDir=sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master_swap&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web_swap&instanceDir=sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web_swap&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master_swap&instanceDir=sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master_swap&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web_swap&instanceDir=sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web_swap&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_testing_index_swap&instanceDir=sitecore_testing_index_swap&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_suggested_test_index_swap&instanceDir=sitecore_suggested_test_index_swap&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_fxm_master_index_swap&instanceDir=sitecore_fxm_master_index_swap&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_fxm_web_index_swap&instanceDir=sitecore_fxm_web_index_swap&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_list_index_swap&instanceDir=sitecore_list_index_swap&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=social_messages_master_swap&instanceDir=social_messages_master_swap&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=social_messages_web_swap&instanceDir=social_messages_web_swap&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=social_messages_master_swap&instanceDir=social_messages_master_swap&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=social_messages_web_swap&instanceDir=social_messages_web_swap&configSet=sitecore_configs
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=sitecore_analytics_index&instanceDir=sitecore_analytics_index&configSet=sitecore_analytic_configs
```

These default SOLR Url's can assist in creating SOLR cores for the OOTB Sitecore 8.2 Indexes as well as their associated "swap" core.  Note that these url's are using SOLR ConfigSets for Sitecore. Create a configset folder called `sitecore_configs` in your SOLR folder and put your Sitecore modified schema.xml file in there. All cores created by these url's will then use the `sitecore_configs` configset.

Comment: What are these 32 indexes called Keith? I haven't seen that many indexes before. There are usually only about 15.

They are listed here for 8.2:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/search_index_descriptions

Do you have any custom indexes?

Comment: +1 for a very thorough response, Pete; great work!  There is a Dan Solvay automated Solr provisioning for Sitecore that is hands off in terms of manually creating Solr cores -- I haven't tried it out, but I think that's the promise of it.  I think it's part of a recent SIM check-in on GitHub.

Comment: Hi Pete! I noticed that in your bonus answer, you gave a different configSet for the analytics config than for all of your other configSets. Was that intentional, or was that just a typo?

Comment: good question. I need to revisit why I did that. =) It might have been something that I was testing to see what the differences between those indexes are when I first went down that path. I'll let you know.  I think you can use the same schema.xml though. (Sitecore and Solr version differences are jumbling together. Sorry!)